# why is a string printing 3 times instead of 1 when using time.sleep with multiprocessing imported?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

so when I import multiprocessing in the same code as my print followed by time.sleep it will print the string 3 times opposed to my requested 1 time. I would like to know why this happens and how to fix this if possible, thank you in advance. My code is as follows.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

print('teeeest')
time.sleep(3)

def test1():
    print('test1')
def test2():
    print('test2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

And the result of the code is as follows:

```
teeeest
teeeest
teeeest
test1
test2
```

(Note 'test1' and 'test2' were sent at this same time as intended)

Comment: @jsbueno Macos does the same thing.

Comment: Does not MacOS have a working "fork"?

Comment: MacOS doesn't use fork only Linux. @jsbueno

Comment: Yes - I checked around - they changed away from fork on Python 3.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use multiprocessing, Python creates a brand new process with a brand-new copy of the interpreter, and starts running your file again from the top. Anything you don't want done in EVERY child needs to be in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: Hmm. When I run the code as is, I only get `teeeest` printed once.

Comment: Linux behaves differently, because it can use `fork` to clone the process and continue running from that spot.

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect an answer that worked this fast. Thank you so much this really helped. I've got new insight on how multiprocessing works and can fix other issues I've faced. @TimRoberts I am however aware of how Linux can fork.

Comment: Interesting! I did indeed run it on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Python creates a new process when you use multiprocessing - and in the Microsoft Windows O.S., the only way for the new process to have the same loaded modules your orignal process had, is to load them all - and Python modules are executed upon loading.

On other O.S.s (MacOs, Linux, etc...) Python uses the "fork" system call which creates a "clone" of the running process as it is, and the modules do not have to be run and executed again.

The behavior under Windows is the motive why any code running with multiprocessing *must* be guarded by an `if __name__ == "__main__":` expression: on the copied process the content of `__name__` is no longer `__main__`, as the former main file is imported by the multiprocessing machinery on the subprocesses.

**update**: it seems that since Python 3.8, on MacOS the default is to use Spawn, not fork - so on Macs you'd get the same behavior. (seem here https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/g5372v/multiprocessing_with_fork_on_macos/ )