# UUID stayed the same for different processes on Centos OS, but works fine on Windows OS (UUID per Process flow)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, uuid

I have two source files that I am running in Python 3.9. (The files are big...)

File one (fileOne.py)

```
# ...
sessionID = uuid.uuid4().hex
# ...
```

File two (fileTwo.py)

```
# ...
from fileOne import sessionID
# ...
```

File two is executed using module multiprocessing.

- When I run on my local machine and print the UUID in file two, it is always unique.
- When I run the script on Centos OS, it somehow remained the same
- If I restart the service, the UUID will change once.

My question: Why does this work locally (Windows OS) as expected, but not on a CentOS VM?

**UPDATE 1.0:**
To make it clear.

For each separate process, I need that UUID will be the same across FileOne and FileTwo. WHich mean

- `processOne = UUID in file one and in file two will be 1q2w3e`
- `processTwo = UUID in file one and in file two will be r4t5y6 (a different one)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your riddle is likely is caused by the way multi-processing works in different operating systems. You don't mention, but your "run locally" is certainly Windows or MacOS, not a Linux or other Unix Flavor.

The thing is that multiprocessing on Linux (and up to a time ago on MacOS, but changed that on Python 3.8), used a system `fork` call when using multiprocessing: the current process is duplicated "as is" with all its defined variables and classes - since your `sessionID` is defined at import time, it stays the same in all subprocesess.

Windows lacks the `fork` call, and multiprocessing resorts to start a new Python interpreter which re-imports all modules from the current process (this leads to another, more common cause of confusion, where any code not guarded by an `if __name__ == "__main__":` on the entry Python file is re-executed). In your case the value for `sessionID` is regenerated.

Check the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

So, if you want the variable to behave reliably and have the same value across all processes when running multiprocessing, you should either pass it as a parameter to the target functions in the other processes, or use a proper structure meant to share values across processes as documented here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

(you can also check this recent question about the same topic: [why is a string printing 3 times instead of 1 when using time.sleep with multiprocessing imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898589/why-is-a-string-printing-3-times-instead-of-1-when-using-time-sleep-with-multipr/))

**If you need a unique ID across files for each different process:**
(As is more clear from the edit and comments)

Have a global (plain) dictionary which will work as a per-process registry for the IDs, and use a function to retrieve the ID - the function can use `os.getpid()` as a key to the registry.

file 1:

```
import os
import uuid
...
_id_registry = {}

def get_session_id():
    return _id_registry.setdefault(os.getpid(), uuid.uuid4())
```

file2:

```
from file1 import get_session_id

sessionID = get_session_id()
```

(the setdefault dict method takes care of providing a new ID value if none was set)

NB.: the registry set up in this way will keep at most the master process ID (if multiprocessing is using `fork` mode) and itself - no data on the siblings, as each process will hold its own copy of the registry.  If you need a working inter-process dictionary (which could hold a live registry for all processes, for example) you will probably be better using [Redis](https://redis.io) for it (certainly one of the Python bindings have a transparent Python-mapping-over-redis, so you don´t have to worry with the semantics of it).

Comment: To make it clear , sorry for making confusion.  For each separate process I need that UUID will be the same between file one and two. WHich mean `processONe = UUID in file one and in file two is 1q2w3e` and `processTwo = UUID in file one and in file two is will be r4t5y6 (different one)`

Comment: I have updated question, to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: updated the answer with a working sugestion.

Answer (score 3):

When you run your script it generate the new value of the uuid, but when you run it inside some service you code the same as:

```
sessionID = 123 # simple constant
```

so to fix the issue you can try wrap the code to the function, for example:

```
def get_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex
```

in you second file:

```
from frileOne import get_uuid

get_uuid()
```

Comment: it looks the question is about how to keep the value the same across multiprocesses, not having a unique one.